# Commands CountDown Timer

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So how to add countdown date time to reply, starts count down once that times finishes it will show ended.

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

start = 20/06/20018 11 PM UTC Time zone
end = 21/06/20018 11 PM UTC Time zone

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def meeting(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Description.", color=0x000000)
    embed.add_field(name="Name", value="Meeting will...", inline=False)
    await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Finally bot says `Meeting will... (Starts in:23 hours 10 minutes)`

I imported `from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta` now how to subtract current time. like i need to add like June 20 2018 11PM UTC time zone - Current time.

[image]

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What kind of help do you need? Stackoverflow isn't a free code-writing service, but we can help if there is some specific part of the problem that you need help with.

Comment: You can just use the datetime library. When the user types `?meeting` you can just   return the day of the meeting minus the current day.

Comment: yes that's what i want i already using manually `Meeting will start at ... 20/06 5pm GMT`  but many of them get confuse with different timezone. So this one tells correctly how many hours left for meeting.

Comment: You can get the current time with `datetime.now()`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  yes i checked `datetime.now()` - `timedelta(days=2)`  but how to add this in `await bot.say`  also i need to make it subtract date from timezone example `datetime.now()` - `21/06/20018 11 PM UTC`

Comment: Still no reply for this question.